# How to create a patch.object mock that I can start() and stop()?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, mixins

So I have a large suite of unit tests in python, and I want to apply a set of 4 patches across all the tests (to disable expensive stuff).

I have about 300 tests over 20 test classes, and I want to want to provide a mixin to my TestCase that applies these patches in setUp, rather than patching each class individually.

I can use `patch.object` to patch each individual test or test class, which is a syntax nightmare for 300 tests but works as intended:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_stuff(self):
        with patch.object('MyClass1', 'mymethod1') as mock_method_1:
            with patch.object('MyClass2', 'mymethod2') as mock_method_2:
                with patch.object('MyClass3', 'mymethod3') as mock_method_3:
                    with patch.object('MyClass4', 'mymethod4') as mock_method_4:
                        # do stuff
                        self.assertEqual(mock_method_4.call_count, 0)
```

Then I made a mixin where I create the same patch but add it to the test class as an attribute, and use the `start()` method. This is completely DRY and I can patch everything at once.

```py
class PatchMixin():

    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_method_1 = patch.object(
            MyClass1, "mymethod1"
        )
        self.mock_method_2 = patch.object(
            MyClass2, "mymethod2"
        )
        self.mock_method_3 = patch.object(
            MyClass3, "mymethod3"
        )
        self.mock_method_4 = patch.object(
            MyClass4, "mymethod4"
        )

        self.mock_method_1.start()
        self.mock_method_2.start()
        self.mock_method_3.start()
        self.mock_method_4.start()

        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.mock_method_1.stop()
        self.mock_method_2.stop()
        self.mock_method_3.stop()
        self.mock_method_4.stop()

        super().tearDown(self)


class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_stuff(self):
        # do stuff
        self.assertEqual(self.mock_method_4.call_count, 0)
```

```
**THE QUESTION**

When running the mixin, it doesn't work. I get an error:
```

Failed: [undefined]AttributeError: '_patch' object has no attribute 'call_count'

```
Why does this error occur, and how can I use `patch.object` (or some equivalent) to store the patch on my class in this way?
```

Comment: You should know that you can 1. Put multiple context managers into one `with` 2. Use (multiple) decorators for the patch 3. Apply the patch to the whole test case (the class) as a decorator and 4. Store a `patch` call into a variable.

Comment: Thanks Klaus, I actually do realise those things but didn't cover them for succinctness in the question. 4 is what I'm trying to achieve but the return value of patch.object doesn't seem to behave that way.

Comment: (I can't use decorators because VSCode's integrated test module then picks them up as the root of each test so the links in the UI all get mashed)

Answer (score 0):

OK I have it. I thought that the patch would be returned, then `start()` method should be called on it. I didn't realise that the return value from calling `start()` is the patch I should be asserting on (ie it's *that* which I should be storing on the class).

So here's the correct mixin working as expected:

```py
class PatchMixin():

    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_method_1 = patch.object(
            MyClass1, "mymethod1"
        ).start()
        # ... others ...
        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.mock_method_1.stop()
        # ... others ...
        super().tearDown()
```